# Basic List Validation

Tags: list, validation

I need to have a list validation using SharePoint 2010. What I am looking for is something like this:

```
if( ( A && B ) || C )
```

Where A, B and C are expressions. I have the first part, A && B working but not the rest. This is what I have for A && B:

```
=AND([FieldA]>[FieldB],[FieldC]>[FieldB])
```

How would I expand this to add an OR statement? The OR will be something like this:

```
[FieldB]>=[FieldD]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would be exactly the same as you have written it in your first code line:

```
=IF( ( AND([FieldA]>[FieldB],[FieldC]>[FieldB]) ), OR([FieldB]>=[FieldD]) )
```